# How to check that both command exit status is zero and stderr is empty in a single statement?

Tags: bash, io-redirection, stderr, string-length, error-code

Some commands write insignificant warnings to `stderr` but return exit status `0`.

Is there a way to check that the command exit status is `0` **and** `stderr` is empty, without creating temporary files and with a single statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [@Cyrus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61468053/3525368) and [@chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61467811/61500863#comment108739498_61468053) for the comments:

```
if stderr=$(command 2>&1 >/dev/null) && test -z "$stderr"; then echo "ok"; fi
```

The `stderr` of the `command 2>&1 >/dev/null` is redirected to where `stdout` was before, and `stdout` itself is redirected to `/dev/null`.
Then the `stderr` is assigned to the `stderr` variable in `stderr=$(command 2>&1 >/dev/null)`, and the exit code of this assignment is the one from just `command`, so it is utilized in `if`. Then, if the exit code of `command` is zero (and only in this case), the second condition (`test -z "$stderr"`) is checked - which is testing if `$stderr` variable is a zero-length string.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest:

```
stderr=$(your_command 2>&1 >/dev/null)
[[ $? == 0 ]] && [[ ${#stderr} == 0 ]] && echo okay
```

Comment: `>/dev/null 2>&1` - well, it's just doing `2>/dev/null`, no?

Comment: @KamilCuk: Yeah, I missed that. I've updated my answer.

Comment: The exit status of the assignment to `stderr` is the exit status of `your_command`; you can fold the two together: `stderr=$(...) && [[ ${#stderr} == 0 }} && echo okay`.

Answer (score 2):

Because of how `set -o pipefail` works, you can grab stderr in a pipe and exit with nonzero exit status from the pipe if there's anything on stderr. So basically `pipefail` does the binary and-ing or exit status - if the command exits with nonzero exit status, `pipefail` fails the pipe with this status, if the command exits with zero exit status, then the right side of the pipe will fail with nonzero exit status so the whole pipe will exit with nonzero exit status.

```
# Usage: exit_if_nonzero_or_stderr command [args...]
# Executes the command [args...] and 
# exits with nonzero exit status
# if the command exits with nonzero exit status
# __or__
# the command outputs anything on stderr.
exit_if_nonzero_or_stderr() {
        (       
                set -o pipefail
                { "$@" 1>&3 ;} 2>&1 | {
                        if IFS= read -r line; then
                                printf "%s\n" "$line"
                                cat 
                                exit 1
                        fi
                } >&2
        ) 3>&1
}
```

Tested against all combinations:

```
tester() { 
        for i in \
                'echo 1; true;' \
                'echo 1; false;' \
                'echo 1; echo 2 >&2; true;' \
                'echo 1; echo 2 >&2; false;'
        do
                eval "f() { $i }"
                set -o pipefail
                exit_if_nonzero_or_stderr f 2> >( \
                        sed 's/^/stderr: /' >&2) | 
                        sed 's/^/stdout: /';
                echo "f() { $i } -> exit status: $?";
        done
}
tester
```

The `tester` outputs:

```
stdout: 1
f() { echo 1; true; } -> exit status: 0
stdout: 1
f() { echo 1; false; } -> exit status: 1
stderr: 2
stdout: 1
f() { echo 1; echo 2 >&2; true; } -> exit status: 1
stdout: 1
stderr: 2
f() { echo 1; echo 2 >&2; false; } -> exit status: 1
```

Alternative implementation and a little more verbose and more memory consuming but more posix-ish you could grab `stderr` to a variable and check if it's nonzero:

```
exit_if_nonzero_or_stderr2() {
        local stderr ret
        # redirect stdout to output with temporary file descriptor
        # and grab stderr 
        { stderr=$({ "$@" 1>&3 ;} 2>&1 ) ;} 3>&1
        # remember return value
        ret=$?
        # if theres anything on stderr, output it
        if [[ -n "$stderr" ]]; then
                cat <<<"$stderr" >&2
                # if stderr, always nonzero
                return 1
        fi
        # else we return with the exit status of the command
        return "$ret"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope below is helpful.

```
 res=$(./test.out 2 >&1)
 if [ $? -eq 0 ];then
    stdout=$res
    echo $stdout
 else
    return_code=$?
    std_err=$res
    echo $stderr 
 fi
```

Corresponding test.c file in C

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   int main ( ) {
       printf( "hello " );
       fprintf( stderr, "HELP!" );
       printf( " world\n" );
       return 1;
   }
```

Comment: there are several issue with this.. `res=$(./test.out 2 >&1)` includes both `stdout` and `stderr`. and also there is no test of `stderr` length